# What is causing Error 15165 in my MSSQL Transactional Replication subscription agent?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) Standard running on Windows 2008.  Bidirectional transactional replication is set up between two servers.  One of the subscription agents just started getting error 15164.  The results of sp_helpsubscriptionerrors is:
Source: MSSQL_ENG
Error: 15165
Text: Could not find object '(null)' or you do not have permission.
Command Id: 320

I have made sure that the SQL Server agent login has both Windows and SQL security access.  Full access to the directory structure and sysadmin access to the SQL Server.

What else can I do to try to troubleshoot/fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve validated the permissions as it sounds like you have, the cause could the performing of an operation on a non-existing object.  To identify which object, run a profiler trace while reproducing the error.  Look for “could not find object” error text so you can identify which object is missing.  For example, a sp_MSrepl procedure could be missing.

Comment: A profiler trace!  Why didn't I think of that?  Thank you sir.